# Why does using Actions > Edit in Datasheet result in <div> ... </div> HTML formatting in the multiple row text area?

Tags: excel

I have a SharePoint List with a column of type 'Multiple lines of Text'. Then I copy a Excel spreadsheet content into the List using `Actions` > `Edit in Datasheet`. Later, when I use a HTML text-area to display the text, it will always include the `<div><font face=Calibri size=2> ... ... </font></div>`.

Is it possible to stop SharePoint from adding other HTML coding beside the ones that I have in my Excel file?

**Example**

I have the following excel file:

```
====================
| Alice and John   |
| Mary and Peter   |
| June and Johnny  |
====================
```

If I copy into the SharePoint list using the `Actions` > `Edit in Datasheet`, and then later using a HTML text-area box, it will display as follows:

```
         ================================================================
Couple:  | <div><font face=Calibri size=2> Alice and John </font></div> |
         ================================================================
```

But what I wanted SharePoint to display was this:

```
         ==================
Couple:  | Alice and John |
         ==================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your "Multiple lines of text" column and, under "Additional Column Settings", set the "**Specify the type of text to allow**" setting value to "**Plain text**". I believe that should prevent SharePoint from adding additional HTML markup to the field value.

Comment: Thanks Vassili, its a bit tricky cause sometime I may need to insert multiple line text into the text box. If the setting value is "Plain text", SharePoint might not allow me to insert multiple line data. Would SharePoint still allow me to insert multiple lines of data given the setting value set to "Plain text" instead of "Rich text"? (I will do some experiments on it, while in the meantime, if you know the answer, please kindly let me know.)

Comment: Thank Vassili. Verified Correct as it retain multiples lines in data when insert into the text box.

Comment: @Jack - yes, you can definitely add multiple lines of text into the field when in "Plain text" mode. You can think of this as a plain text file you create in Notepad - anything you can do in Notepad you can do in a "Plain text" field.

Comment: Yeap, I done some experiment and verified that multiple lines of text can work. However, all the formatting such as bold font will not be available.